# Getting the selected date in a rendered calendar

Tags: java, ajax, primefaces, calendar

The attribute rendered that I am using to display or hide the calendar in primefaces makes impossible to get the date selected from the calendar.

I tried to delete it, then it works well.
So, is there anything missing to my code ??

```
<p:outputLabel  style="width:20%" value="Time unit"></p:outputLabel>
 <p:selectOneRadio style="width:34%;margin-left:20%" id="choix" value="#{graphe.choix_aff}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Month" itemValue="mois" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Day" itemValue="jour" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Hour" itemValue="heure" />
        <p:ajax update="panel"  listener="#{graphe.handleChange}" />           
 </p:selectOneRadio>


<p:outputPanel id="panel"  >   
 <p:outputLabel  style="width:20%" value="Analysis frame"></p:outputLabel>
<p:calendar  update="@form" style="width:600px" rendered="#{graphe.cal_affiche}" id="popup1" value="#{graphe.date1}" >
<p:ajax event="dateSelect"  listener="#{graphe.dateSelectedAction1}">
</p:ajax>
 </p:calendar>          


<p:commandButton value="View Graph"   actionListener="#{graphe.selected}" />
```

Thank you